# Access a folder located in the home screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, directory, jailbreak

I'm writing an app for iPad. 
In this app, I have a screen made to automatically goto other applications.

For example, if I click on a button my app reduces and the music app opens

```
NSString *stringURL = @"music:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

What I would also like to do is to reduce the app and automatically open a folder in the home screen (in that case a game folder cleverly called "Games").

Technically this folder is not within the app sandbox because it's located on the home screen of the device with the icons of the applications. I don't know if the home folders actually have a path. They seems to be more like a group of application icons (they are created by dragging icons on top of another).

Is there a way to open this folder the same way I open the music app for example ?

EDIT: This app is not intended to be posted on the App Store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this was answered before the user added **This app is not intended to be posted on the App Store**

Simple **NO** and you have answered your own question by saying `"this folder is not within the app sandbox because it's located on the home screen"` you can't access anything outside the apps designated container so no this isn't possible and would probably get rejected for a range of reasons the main one being:

> **2.6** Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I forgot to add that this app is not intended to be published on the App Store. So the rejection is not a problem. Is there technically a way to do that ?

Comment: @CharlesDonnefort unfortunately I can't help you then I don't normally do jailbroken work.

Comment: Okay so it's only doable on a jailbreaked device ?

Comment: I see that there is some applications that are made for file management. So if I understand well this kind of application access files outside the app sandbox. Is there some exceptions to that rule ? (even though the paragraph 2.6 that you copied is quite straightforward to say the least !)

Comment: If your application isn't intended for the app store then you can ignore the 2.6 rule. If it is to be distributed to jailbroken devices or through ad-hoc distribution that you don't have to stick to those rules and you can do whatever you want. Unfortunately I don't do these kinds of apps I only do apps that go into the app store so unfortunately I can't help with this, but it is perfectly possible using private APIs.